# What does associativity mean for orders?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, associativity

I'm watching the class [Category Theory for Programmers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_) and it's said that an order (preorder, partial order, or total order) constitutes a category, and one of the conditions for this is that the relation is associative.

I understand how and why $(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)$, in the sense that the order of applying the $+$ operator doesn't matter - after doing $x+y$ I get a number $w$, then I can do $w+z$.

However I don't really understand what $(a\leq b)\leq c$ means. $(a\leq b)$ doesn't produce a number like $(x+y)$; it's just a true/false value of whether or not $a$ is less than or equal to $b$.

What does it mean to ask "is $a$ is smaller than $b$ smaller than $c$"?

What's a better interpretation of asking whether an order is associative?

Comment: Maybe the interpretation you're looking for is 'transitivity'...

Comment: As Mockingbird is maybe hinting at, it is possible that the wrong terminology is being used here. I suspect the lecturer might actually mean "transitive" as discussed in [this wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

Comment: Transitivity is another condition for a category. Having an arrow from `a` to `b` means `a<=b`, and arrows a->b, b->c require there exists an arrow a->c, this is provided by the transitivity of the order.

However, given these arrows, we need to have (a->b)->c = a->(b->c) which requires the same of the relation. That's the part I don't get.

Comment: Without brackets, $a\le b\le c$ is short for $a\le b\land b\le c$, which implies $a\le c$. If you read $(a\le b)\le c$ somewhere, that might be an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) (which outside of programming would use square brackets), i.e. $(a\le b)$ is $1$ if $a\le b$ or $0$ otherwise.

Comment: thanks @J.G., translating the statement as a conjunction does show the meaning of the expression and in a way also shows that the brackets don't matter. In face, they make the meaning less clear by forcing an evaluation of one inequality and making it one of the sides of the second inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think part of your confusion is just the notation being used. To make a poset into a category, you have precisely one morphism from $a$ to $b$ exactly if $a \leq b$, but $a \leq b$ is not (usually) the "name" of that morphism. For the purposes of this answer, we'll call such a morphism (if it exists) $l_{a, b} \in \hom(a, b)$.

The key idea that will affect everything below is that elements of $\hom(a, b)$ are unique if they exist (for this kind of category - this is not true for all categories). For any morphisms $f, g \in \hom(a, b)$, $f = g$ because both $f$ and $g$ are equal to $l_{a, b}$.

The axioms of a category then require that there is an identity morphism $\mathrm{id}_a : a \to a$, indicating that the relation $\leq$ needs to be reflexive ($a \leq a$). Since there's exactly one morphism between two objects if it exists, $\mathrm{id}_a$ must be $l_{a, a}$.

Next, we require composition: a map $\hom(b, c) \times \hom(a, b) \to \hom(a, c)$. Remembering that $\hom(a, b)$ is inhabited (by $l_{a, b}$) exactly if $a \leq b$, this translates to transitivity of the relation: $ b \leq c$ and $a \leq b$ implies $a \leq c$.

But what is $l_{b, c} \circ l_{a, b}$? We know that it's an element of $\hom(a, c)$, but that set has at most one element, and if it has any element, it's $l_{a, c}$. So $l_{b, c} \circ l_{a, b} = l_{a, c}$.

The other conditions talk about equality of morphisms. But remember that any morphisms with the same domain and codomain are equal, so these equalities are all trivial.

Left identity is $\mathrm{id}_b \circ f = f$ for all morphisms $f \in \hom(a, b)$. Both sides of the equality are morphisms from $a$ to $b$, so they're automatically equal. Similarly, right identity, $f \circ \mathrm{id}_a = f$ is trivially true.

Associativity says that for morphisms $f \in \hom(c, d)$, $g \in \hom(b, c)$ and $h \in \hom(a, b)$, $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$. Both sides of the equality are morphisms from $a$ to $d$, so they are trivially equal once again. Both sides would equal $l_{a, d}$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I can see now that associativity of morphisms doesn't translate directly to saying `(a<=b)<=c = a<=(b<=c)`

What does 'poset' mean? a partial order and a set?

Comment: Don't worry about that it's just a set with a partial order, same as what you're talking about. Preorders are slightly more general, but any preorder can be made into a partial order in a canonical way.